# Why can't I use more than two registers in inline asm?

Tags: c, assembly, cpu-registers

I'm trying to use assembly in a part of my code, but I need to use more than one variable. Why can't I use more than two registers for C variables?

```
__asm(
"add %eex, %edx\n"
"add %eax, %ecx\n"
"mov 1 ,%0\n"
:"=r"(side)
:"a"(map.y));
:"e"(sdist.y)
:"d"(delta.y)
:"c"(step.y)
);
```

When I compile this, I get the error

```
a.c: In function ‘main’:
a.c:289:2: error: expected expression before ‘:’ token
  :"e"(sdist.y)
  ^
a.c:292:1: error: expected statement before ‘)’ token
  );
```

Comment: maybe the trailing semicolon or extra parathesis on this line? `:"a"(map.y));`

Comment: Is that `);` supposed to be there, right at the spot where the compiler flags an error?

Comment: Note that there's no EEX register, and the "e" constraint doesn't indicate a register operand.

Comment: **That's super broken in a whole bunch of other ways**, including syntax (multiple input operands should be separated by commas), `1` is the absolute address `1`; maybe you meant `$1` immediate or `%1` operand?  Also, an `"e"` constraint for x86 is an immediate that fits in 32-bit sign-extended; there is no `eex` register.  Your other input constraints are all specific-register.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html#Machine-Constraints.  Oh also, this destroys the values in read-only input operands like EDX and ECX, violating the constraints.

Comment: TL:DR: see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info for links to guides and tutorials.  **Throwing code at the wall until it sticks is even worse than usual with GNU C inline asm**: it's easy (if you get the constraints even subtly wrong) to make code that happens to work correctly with one set of surrounding code but breaks with different optimization options, or with minor changes to other code.  Make sure you understand exactly what everything does, and why it's safe, before signing off on a piece of inline asm.  Or don't use it.

Comment: Don't try to learn assembly through inline assembly.  It only makes it much more confusing.

Comment: Russel, it's not really considered "good form" to make changes to your question so much that it invalidates comments and/or answers. By all means *add* notes to your question to elucidate, but wholesale changes invalidating answers makes it basically useless for future visitors. Have rolled back to the original.

Comment: @paxdiablo  Nothing wrong with invalidating comments, only existing answers.  As this question is closed trying to fix the problems with it so it can be reopened probably takes precedence, but it's a moot point, because its unlikely that the question is fixable.

Comment: @RossRidge: Agreed; there's so much wrong with it (and no context for what the OP wants it to do) that the only answer is "read a tutorial".

Answer (score 4):

For that *specific* error, the `);` should *not* be where you have it (where I've indicated below).

```
__asm(
"add %eex, %edx\n"
"add %eax, %ecx\n"
"mov 1 ,%0\n"
:"=r"(side)
:"a"(map.y));    <---
:"e"(sdist.y)
:"d"(delta.y)
:"c"(step.y)
);
```

It closes off the entire `asm` statement, something that's also done on your final line. At a *guess,* I'd say you just added the three extra registers `e`, `d` and `c`, along with the new closing line, but without first adjusting the original closing line (register `a`).

Regardless of *why* you did it, the outcome is that the `:"e"(sdist.y)` is back in *C* land and therefore invalid.

---

There are numerous *other* errors in your code even once you've fixed that immediate problem, such as (may not be an *exhaustive* list):

- multiple input operands should be separated by commas;
- `1` is the absolute address 1 - you possible meant to write `$1` for an immediate value, or `%1` for an operand;
- an `e` constraint for x86 is an immediate that fits in 32-bit sign-extended, and there is no `eex` register;
- this destroys the values in read-only input operands like `edx` and `ecx`, violating the constraints.

Comment: It still comes up with the same error

Comment: @Russell356: Like I commented under the question, your code is jam packed with other major errors including  syntax errors.

Comment: @Peter, all excellent points, I hope you don't mind that I've incorporated them into the answer as an addendum (since it makes it so much more useful).

Comment: Yup, that got my upvote :)  That info definitely belongs in an answer.